# mobile swipe navigation examples

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation

Recently I am creating a page with a small menu in the content, just to switch between different content topics. Nearly similar to a small slideshow, just with a simple line navigation above the content with the different topics. 
So I am just looking through the web to find some alternative ideas for the typicall hamburger icon for the mobile version, since I am using it already for the main navigation.

I found this:

```
'http://codepen.io/fbrz/pen/bNdMwZ'
```

I dont want to use the pull-down function, but I love how the different menuitems appear and come from outside the content area in focus. 
So I had the Idea of maybe just using the swipe menu-items, without the pull down function.

So my question is, did anybody of you have found or even created a similar navigation somewhere, and if yes where? I would love to find some more options/ideas?

Thanks as always for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be something useful for you 
[Scroll Overflow Menu](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/23/scroll-overflow-menu/)

Comment: thanks for your link! I created something similar my own now, but always good to have some more inspiration!